# Map Navigation Application that Builds on Top of Google Maps

Tags: iphone

Is there a map navigation application ( GPS app) that is built on top of google maps? Something like papago, but it is too expensive for my taste.

It would be better if that GPS can alert me on the current road condition ( whether there is a massive traffic jam ahead of current route) and suggest me alternative.

Edit: If GPS apps are not allowed to build on top of Google Maps, is there a GPS app that can check on traffic condition and suggest me alternative route?

I'm living in Malaysia, if that's important to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently both Google Maps and Waze provide turn by turn navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation implies turn-by-turn directions. When iOS 4 was announced, Apple stated that background navigation was one of the "poles in the tent" (one of the big 6 new features that made up the iOS 4 upgrade). However, per their licensing agreement, developers are NOT allowed to leverage Google Maps when building driving direction applications. They must build off their own data. That is why all the other apps you see (TomTom, Navigon, OpenStreetMap, etc.) all look unique, and have their own data.

Comment: If GPS apps are not allowed to build on top of Google Maps, is there a GPS app that can check on traffic condition and suggest me alternative route?

Comment: I don't use driving direction apps, so I can't answer, personally. Now that you have a specific way of framing a followup question, I suggest searching for "iPhone Navigation Apps", and if you don't find a satisfactory answer, with respect to your country, ask a new question! :)